# How to refer 2 template html file (mobile and desktop) dynamically in single component in angular 6?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

My approach is as below.

Folder structure

mobile-view.component.html

```
<p> this is mobile view</p>
```

desktop-view.component.html

```
<p> this is desktop view</p>
```

mobile.component.ts

```ts
import { BaseComponent } from './base.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-mobile-view',
    templateUrl: './mobile-view.component.html'
})

export class MobileComponent extends BaseComponent { }
```

desktop.component.ts

```ts
import { BaseComponent } from './base.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-desktop-view',
    templateUrl: './desktop-view.component.html'
})

export class DesktopComponent extends BaseComponent { }
```

base.component.ts

```ts
@Component({
   selector: 'app-root',
   template: `<app-mobile-view *ngIf="isMobileView"></app-mobile-view>

    <app-desktop-view *ngIf="!isMobileView"></app-desktop-view>`
})
export class BaseComponent implements {

   isMobileView: boolean;

   constructor(){
        if (navigator.userAgent &&
           (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) ||
           navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i) ||
           navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) ||
           navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i) ||
           navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i))) {

           this.isMobileView = true;
        } else {
           this.isMobileView = false;
        }
   }

   ngOnInit() {
    // code
   }

   // various methods
}
```

In this approach my main logic and all binding variables reside in base.component.ts

Mobile component and Desktop component extends Base component to access all methods and variables

Note:- This is demo code just for understanding what i have tried.

Requirement :

1. AOT build is must.
2. Need any better approach or standard practice for
       achieving this
3. Need a way to set template dynamically based on
       device from which it is     request. Refer base.component.html
       constructor for code of getting     userAgent(provide info of 
       device
       from which request is comming) which i am using currently.

Previous method used:-

main.component.html

```ts
@Component({
   selector: 'app-root',
   template: function () {
     if (isMobileUser()) {
            return require('./mobile-view.component.html');
       } else {
            return require('./desktop-view.component.html');
       }
     }(),
    styleUrls: ['./main.component.scss']
})

export class MainComponent {
}
```

1. In this approach AOT build is failing
2. function call in component decorator is deprecated

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this approach which is simpler when compared to above one. using ngContainer with ngTemplateoutlet, you can inject the template into the container based on condition.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-mobiledesktop-view',
    templateUrl: './mobiledesktop-view.component.html'
})

export class MobileDesktopComponent { }


**Template:**

<ng-template #mobileView>
  This is mobile view
</ng-template>

<ng-template #desktopView>
  This is desktop view
</ng-template>

<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="isDesktop ? desktopView : mobileView">

</ng-container>
```

**Using Dynamic Component:**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-desktop-view',
    template: 'This is desktop view'
})

export class AppDesktopComponent { }

@Component({
    selector: 'app-mobile-view',
    template: 'This is mobile view'
})

export class AppMobileComponent { }

@Component({
    selector: 'app-container-view',
    template: ' <ng-container #messagecontainer></ng-container>'
})

export class AppContainerComponent { 
     private componentRef;
     @ViewChild('messagecontainer', { read: ViewContainerRef }) entry: ViewContainerRef;
     constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

     ngAfterViewInit(){
        const component = (isDesktop) ? AppDesktopComponent : AppMobileComponent;
        const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(component);
        this.componentRef = this.entry.createComponent(factory);
        //this.componentRef.instance.data = appData;
     }

     ngOnDestroy() {
        this.componentRef.destroy();
     }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to keep two html templates in separate files?

Comment: you cannpt maintain as 2 separate template files. IT won't be supported in AOT build. You can opt for creating 2 components (desktop and mobile). Your container component will dynamically insert the component at runtime using ViewContainerRef and resolveComponentFactory.